# How to sort a Pandas Dataframe with different criteria in one column

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I want to sort this data frame by currency as follows: Dollar, Euro, Franc,  and the rest in alphabetical order. How Can I do that ... I just know the way to sort by ascending alphabetically.

```
Country     Currency
--------------------
Ilandia     Franc
dinamarca   Pound
Colombia    Peso
Venezuela   Bolivar
USA         Dolar
UK          Pound
```

Comment: Don't share code or data as an image, instead share it in the question  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question, also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does `df.sort_values('moneda', ascending=True)` help you?

Comment: Actually this is half of the problem, first I need to do the order of the criteria and then ascendingly..but thanks!